# Sorting with Isotope Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-isotope

I am fairly new to javascript and I can not figure out why my sorting is not working.  The filtering part is working fine with a minor problem(I can't seem to get it to center my section "portfolio").  I have read through all of the Isotope pages and even multiple on here but nothing matches my issue.

Here is my code which is basically copied form Isotope, I would really appreciate it if someone could help me figure out why this is not working:

```
<div id="sorts" class="button-group">
<button data-sort-by="original-order">original order</button>
<button data-sort-by="name">name</button>
<button data-sort-by="symbol">symbol</button>
<button data-sort-by="number">number</button>
<button data-sort-by="weight">weight</button>
<button data-sort-by="category">category</button>
</div>

<section class="portfolio">
<article class="entry video"><img src="baldwin.jpg" alt=""/>
<span class="magnifier"></span>
<h3 class="name">Baldwin</h3>
<p class="symbol">Hg</p>
<p class="number">80</p>
<p class="weight">200.59</p>
</article>
<article class="entry modern">
<img src="berkley.jpg" alt="">
<span class="magnifier"></span>
<h3 class="name">Berkley</h3>
<p class="symbol">Te</p>
<p class="number">52</p>
<p class="weight">127.6</p>
</article>
```

And my jquery:

```
<script>
//sorting
$(function() {
var $container = $('.portfolio').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.entry',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  transitionDuration: '0.6s',
  getSortData: {
   name: '.name',
   symbol: '.symbol',
   number: '.number parseInt',
   weight: function( itemElem ) {
    var weight = $( itemElem ).find('.weight').text();
    return parseFloat( weight.replace( /[\(\)]/g, '') );
    }
 }
// initial sortBy from button group
// sortBy: $buttonGroup.find(':checked').val()
});
$('#sorts').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
var sortByValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-by');
$container.isotope({ sortBy: sortByValue });
 });
});
//filtering
var $container = $('.portfolio');
   $container.isotope({
        filter: '*',
        animationOptions: {
         duration: 750,
         easing: 'linear',
         queue: false,
     }
 });

 $('nav.primary ul a').click(function(){
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: selector,
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false,
        }
    });
    return false;
  });

  var $optionSets = $('nav.primary ul'),
       $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

       $optionLinks.click(function(){
          var $this = $(this);
      // don't proceed if already selected
      if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
          return false;
      }
   var $optionSet = $this.parents('nav.primary ul');
   $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
   $this.addClass('selected'); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: centering items is typically a function of CSS - can you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: I can center it through CSS when I remove the jquery for the filtering.  Once that's off it centers.  I put the code back in and it doesn't center anymore.

Comment: try putting `!important` next to the css center property that you have. The code may be using an inline rule that overrides the `text-align: center` or however you have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some errors in your HTML and javascript. I was able to get the script working with the JS below:

```
$(function() {
  var $container = $('.portfolio').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.entry',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  transitionDuration: '0.6s',
  getSortData: {
    name: '.name',
    symbol: '.symbol',
    number: '.number parseInt',
    weight: function( itemElem ) {
      var weight = $( itemElem ).find('.weight').text();
      return parseFloat( weight.replace( /[\(\)]/g, '') );
      }
   }
// initial sortBy from button group
// sortBy: $buttonGroup.find(':checked').val()
});
   $('#sorts').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
   var sortByValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-by');
   $container.isotope({ sortBy: sortByValue });
  });
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pixelsmith/w1p3oto5/).

You've left out a `$` at the start of the main isotope function, and the `section` isn't closed.

I'm not sure what you're using the variable 'ID' for or how you're calling that function, but the code above will work.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much Pixelsmith for your help.  I am still not able to get it work.  Am I linking to the correct sources? [<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>]

Comment: Or could it be the other jquery for the filtering that's doing something?  The filtering works but maybe there is different code I need to add to make them work together.

Comment: Regarding your first comment, no, I don't think you're linking to the correct scripts. Here are two CDN links that you can use.
jQuery: `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js`
Isotope: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/2.1.1/isotope.pkgd.js`

As to your second question, I don't know what other jQuery you're talking about. You can use the development tools on your browser to find out what's not working. Or if you throw up a test page I can have a look.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I think I might of answered my own question.  It works if I remove the jquery for filtering but when I put it back in it stops working while the filtering still works.  I've replaced the jquery code up top with the current code I have including the jquery for the filtering.  Thank you so much again for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad you sorted it out. Please don't forget to mark my answer as correct if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: I only partially sorted it out.  It doesn't work with the filtering.  Is there some way to combine them?

Comment: Sorry to hear it's still not working.

I don't know what you want to combine. You have the filtering code, and some other jQuery code that I don't know about. Can you set up a new [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with your code to show me what's not working?

Comment: I have set it up http://jsfiddle.net/cpuaqfvo/ I have the filtering code and the sorting code but when they are together sorting does not work.  When I use one or the other they each work.  I'm guessing there is something I need to do to combine them.

Comment: In the new fiddle the browser is breaking here: `$('#sorts').on( 'click', 'button', function() {` I rewrote the line `$('#sorts button').click(function() {` and it worked. That didn't make sense to me, since the original line had correct syntax. Then I realized that you'd chosen jQuery 1.6.4 on the fiddle, which doesn't support the `on` syntax; [it was added in jQ v1.7](http://api.jquery.com/on/). So if you're using jQ 1.6.4 on your site, rewrite the `#sorts` function or updated to a newer version of jQ which supports your syntax. [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pixelsmith/wn93dew6/)